# Phonegap HTML page redirect

Tags: javascript, android, html, redirect, cordova

I want to transfer from the index.html page to another page 
I made a ref tag  
it succesfully redirected me to the other page but I want to put some 
alerts to be view on the other page 
I made a JS function that contains that alert

`function testFoo(){ navigator.notification.alert("test alert")}`

then called the function in

```
<body onload="testFoo()"> 
. 
. 
. 
</body>
```

But the alert is giving me a an input text field & a strange message

```
---->  []
```

when I hit ok or cancel 
it askes for --> getToken, usePolling 
& some strange stuff

I'm using android Emulator
ANy ideas ??

Comment: please post the code for the testFoo() function

Comment: testFoo(){ navigator.notification.alert("test alert")}

Comment: Any stuff here you can use? http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html

Comment: We are having the same problem with the empty alert box, that somtimes show getToke() and usePolling(). Have no clue what so ever what's causing this. We are using phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in 0.9.6.  Download the 1.0.0rc1 candidate for the fix.